# objective c classes for Exchange 2007 Web Service (EWS)

Tags: iphone, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I used wsdltoobjc tool for create objective c class for EWS,but i got lot of erros when build application.

I also **tried sudzc. i got error like "Client The request failed schema validation".**

if anyone know about this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below link. u can find the problems related with Sudzc and other tools.
the below site helped me lot. **check Issues That Might Come Up with Sudzc**

http://blog.exadel.com/working-with-ios-and-soap/